# How to divide SQL results into categories

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to generate reports out of a SQL Server database that look like this:

- % of entries < X
- X < % of entries < Y
- % of entries >= Y
- mean value of all entry values
- standard deviation of all entries

So basically, I'm splitting the the content of the db into "below average", "on average" and "above average" categories, which sounds simple enough on paper but apparently takes a lot more work to relay into SQL instructions.

After some search, it appears the only way to go about this is querying the database 5 times with different requests. And calculating the percentage of entries that fall within each of the categories seems impossible with SQL (like count(criteria) / count(*), but this one doesn't work).

Can this be accomplished on SQL Server at all or do I have to query all the information and build the values in code, offline?

Comment: *splitting the content of the db*... what do you mean? Are you returning results, using this in a procedure, calculating rows in a table.... etc? I think you've simplified this too much for anyone to answer. There are many aggregation methods that can do this, depending on what the real use case is. Especially with conditional aggregation and window functions.

Comment: How do you get x which I assume is the lower bound and y which I assume is the upper bound???

Comment: `count(criteria) / count(*)` doesn't work?, you mean it gives you integer division?, you could use `count(criteria)*1.0 / count(*)` instead

Comment: @scsimon I just want to calculate the percentage of entries that fall into each one of the categories I described to produce a report of sorts. Think monthly quality reports of "below production quota", "on production quota", "above production quota" style.

Comment: @RyanWilson the bounds are preset values that are different for each of these queries. They should not pertain to the solution so I omitted them.

Comment: @Lamak Thanks for that, you were right! It mistakenly used integer division, with an additional *1.0 it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation and a single query:

```
select avg(case when val < @x then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio_lt_x,
       avg(case when val > @x and val < @y then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio_bt_x_y,
       avg(case when val >= @y then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio_gt_y,
       avg(val), stdev(val)
from t;
```